# Order of the paste item while using Range.PasteAndFormat c#

Tags: c#, ms-word, office-interop

I am attempting to paste text in a loop using Word automation using the following code.

```cs
Clipboard.SetData(System.Windows.DataFormats.Rtf, text);
if (!Clipboard.ContainsText())
    Thread.Sleep(500);

initialRange.PasteAndFormat(WdRecoveryType.wdFormatOriginalFormatting);
initialRange.Collapse(WdCollapseDirection.wdCollapseEnd);
```

I have a collection of strings which I attempt to write:

> This is line 1
>   This is line 2
>   This is line 3

and I expect the output to be printed in same order, but while using the above code I get output in reverse order i.e.

> This is line 3
>   This is line 2
>   This is line 1

Any idea what I need to do in order to fix the order of the output?

Comment: Have You tryied to debug step by step ? Does it write new line above last one ? Are You sure You have proper order in Clipboard ?

Comment: @KubaDo order in which text items appear in loop is appropriate. Seems like I need to move to the end of the range every time after paste call but not sure how I can achieve that.

Comment: @KubaDo another observation is in above code if I use range.PasteSpecial instead of range.PasteAndFormat then order of text is correct but in that case source formatting is not maintained

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I figured out the fix. I had to add

"initialRange.MoveEnd();" line before PasteAndFormat call.

Hence, final code looks like

```
Clipboard.SetData(System.Windows.DataFormats.Rtf, text);
if (!Clipboard.ContainsData(DataFormats.Rtf))
    Thread.Sleep(500);

initialRange.MoveEnd();
initialRange.PasteAndFormat(WdRecoveryType.wdFormatOriginalFormatting);
initialRange.Collapse(WdCollapseDirection.wdCollapseEnd);
```